# Understand the fission process

Tags: nuclear-physics

I would like to be able to understand what the fission process is like (ideally, from total ignorance). What references could I read? Would it be more convenient to read chemistry books than physics books?
From what I understand, the fission process involves "breaking" the nucleus of an atom. Regarding this: Is any atom fissile? Is there some non-fissile atom? Can this process be understood mathematically?
Thank you so much.

Comment: *from total ignorance … What references could I read?* I suggest starting with a general-purpose reference like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission). If you don’t understand something *specific* that you read there, you can ask for an explanation here.

Comment: *Can this process be understood mathematically?* Yes, but are you a high-school student, a university student, or not a student?

Comment: *Would it be more convenient to read chemistry books than physics books?* No. I don’t think that most chemists concern themselves with fission. (But there are nuclear chemists.)

Comment: I'm an university student.

Comment: The basics you will need to understand are: 1. Electrostatic force causes protons to repel. 2. The strong nuclear force causes nucleons to attract. 3. The combination of the two forces creates a potential energy barrier which makes the nucleus semi-stable. 4. But occasionally quantum tunneling through this barrier allows spontaneous fission. You may find [this short PDF](https://phas.ubc.ca/~stamp/TEACHING/PHYS340/SLIDES/PDF/P340-06--PP26-nuclei.pdf) helpful.

Comment: try the wikipedia page for starters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, atoms aren't fissile. Nuclei (or bulk elements) are.

Few nuclei are fissile.

The mathematical description of fission is a huge subject, for reasons. It requires knowing at least quantum mechanics (QM), scattering theory, many-body QM, computational methods, and of course nuclear physics. It is not computable from first principles so any understanding requires familiarity with experimental nuclear physics, as data are required to constrain calculations.

A summary of advanced methods can be found here:

https://t2.lanl.gov/fiesta2017/school/Younes_Slides.pdf

https://t2.lanl.gov/fiesta2017/school/Lisowski_Slides.pdf

Comment: Thanks by the slides, but, i think that in my case, I need a book (because, in general, slides don't explains the subject step by step)

Comment: the slides are there to forewarn you.